# One window with two layers in it

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I want to resize one layer, but not the other.  How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mark one layer as active by selecting it in the Layers, then press `Ctrl-A` so select all and then `Ctrl-T` to transform, you will effectively only resize the layer you selected. Is that what you were looking for? (If not, please include a screenshot)